# How to prevent Docker causing my .local address to resolve to 172.29.0.1?

Tags: networking, dns, docker

I have a recently installed machine (called `vader`), with a custom DNS entry on my Pi-hole.  This works, when I try to resolve `vader.home`:

```
$ resolvectl query vader.home
vader.home: 192.168.1.212                      -- link: wlp12s0

-- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 6.1ms.
-- Data is authenticated: no; Data was acquired via local or encrypted transport: no
-- Data from: network
```

However, my multicast DNS lookup is returning a few addresses:

```
$ resolvectl query vader.local
vader.local: 192.168.1.212                     -- link: wlp12s0
             172.17.0.1                        -- link: docker0
             172.29.0.1                        -- link: br-462118ed237e
             fe80::9666:a33c:1c7a:2b29%3       -- link: wlp12s0
             fe80::42:2ff:feee:99f5%243        -- link: br-462118ed237e
             fe80::50db:73ff:fe4d:ee9%297      -- link: veth329abca
```

... and the "wrong" one is being used by utilities like `ping`:

```
$ ping vader.local
PING vader.local (172.29.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from vader (172.29.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.018 ms
64 bytes from vader (172.29.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.039 ms
64 bytes from vader (172.29.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
64 bytes from vader (172.29.0.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.038 ms
```

I'd have expected `ping` to use `192.168.1.212`.

Note that `172.17.0.1` and `172.29.0.1` are both created by Docker (one is a bridge):

```
$ ip address | grep 172
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
    inet 172.29.0.1/16 brd 172.29.255.255 scope global br-462118ed237e
```

I couldn't find any *explicit* configuration causing this to happen.  Anyone have any idea how to undo it?

Comment: 172.17.0.1/16 and 172.29.0.1/16 are Docker created networks for each container (or container stack with Docker Compose). You can't and shouldn't remove these. Could you explain what the problem with the current setup is?

Comment: Don't use `dig` with `.local`. It gives wrong answers. Pay attention to the "WARNING: .local is reserved for Multicast DNS;; You are currently testing what happens when an mDNS query is leaked to DNS" part. Either use `ping` or `resolvectl query`. Anyway I have Docker but not this problem, so try making sure that you're using Avahi to supply `.local` not systemd-resolved

Comment: Hah!  A friend just messaged me to say "If you use dig you are *old*".  Guilty as charged :)  Have edited the question; hopefully it sheds some more light.  Will investigate which of `avahi` or `systemd-resolved` is responding - starting by reading up on how to investigate it :)

Comment: @ArturMeinild the problem is that, e.g. if I try to ping `vader.home` and `vader.local` I want them both to resolve to `192.168.1.212`.  Currently, they don't.

Comment: What's `cat /etc/resolv.conf /etc/hosts ; hostnamectl`? If it contains .local, consider changing it

Comment: @DanielT nope, they're as expected:

127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       vader

... and ...

 Static hostname: vader